# AFNetworking handle success in the request thread

Tags: grand-central-dispatch, afnetworking-2

I'm using AFNetworking to fetch JSON data.

I am using the basic style:

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:serverPath];
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

 ... Set custom stuff in header ...
 [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
 ... setup post data ...      

 AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation1, id responseObject) {
    id jsonResponse = [self parseJsonResult:responseObject];
    // Potentially long running operation
    [handler onSuccess:jsonResponse];

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation1, NSError *error) {
    NSInteger httpStatus = [[operation1 response] statusCode];
    // Do some error handling

}
```

Some of the JSON responses take a lot of time to process. This is causing some UI blocking. So now I want to move the response handling off the main thread. Is there an easy way to have the success and failure calls executed in the transport thread instead of the main thread?

I was going to just wrap them in their own *dispatch group* and *dispatch queue* but I don't want any other queued up network requests to happen while I am still parsing/handling the current response.

I thought I would ask before I go spelunking through the libraries code.

Comment: Is it a specific requirement that responses are parsed on the request thread? Or just that they aren't parsed on the *main* thread?

Comment: I's not a requirement to parse on the request thread but other queued HTTP requests should not happen until the long running responses are finished processing.

Answer (score 0):

It was easiest to not use AFNetworking for my long running response processing. I decided to just use

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^ {
       [self processRequestsSycnrounously]

});
```

and drive my own request queue synchronously using something like:

```
NSData* result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request  returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

instead of using:

```
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation1, id responseObject)
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation1, id responseObject) {
    id jsonResponse = [self parseJsonResult:responseObject];
    [handler onSuccess:jsonResponse];
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation1, NSError *error) {
    ... blah blah blah
}
```

This does exactly what I needed to do and was quite easy to use the same success and failure blocks that I already had from AFNetworking code.